# Hibernate doing a delete query when I try to update an object in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_books")
public class Book{
private int id_book;
private String isbn;
private Set<Author> authors;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="tbl_books_tbl_authors",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_book")},
            inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="id_author")})    
public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
    return authors;
}
public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
    this.authors = authors;
}
```

This is the function in BookController for updating the book info:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String dataBook(@Valid BookBean bb, BindingResult result){

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "redirect:/books/formBook";
    }

    booksService.saveBook(bb);

    return "redirect:/books";
}
```

In booksService I have this one:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void saveBook(BookBean lb) {
    DataParser dp = new DataParser();

    booksDAO.sBook(dp.fromBookBeanToBook(lb));

}
```

In booksDAO:

```
@Override
public void sBook(Book book) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(book);
}
```

Then, when I try to update a Book from that form Hibertate does this:

```
Hibernate: update tbl_books set date=?, isbn=? where id_book=?
Hibernate: delete from tbl_books_tbl_authors where id_book=?
```

Why does Hibernate do this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it, when trying to update the Authors Set was empty, so Hibernate did a delete instead of update.